# cross origin policy, using remote page but access localhost data in the same computer

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

I am using a web app say at http://www.stackoverflow.com and in that page i need to populate a dropdown list with mysql data from another computer which is at 192.168.1.145 that runs on wamp.

I heard that this can be done if we configure the cross origin policy method at the headers and at the ajax ( prefer jquery method )

thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, i am in the same network with that 192.168.1.145